# Use a button to change a value in a Spring Object

Tags: java, html, spring, model-view-controller

I am trying to set a boolean via this builder set method. But I cannot figure out how to call it in the html when you click the link. What I want to do is set the value to true when the link is clicked. Any ideas?
The boolean is in a java object in a spring mvc. I have had some success with accessing the object with other methods to get values to display inside the html. But, now I want to alter a value of the object for later use.

This works fine

```
<td>${(application.applicant.employeeCode)!"-"}</td> 
This is the html button that I want to change
<td>
    <#if (application.applicant.agreementPDF)??>
      <a href="/store/${(storeId)!}/view/new/${(application.id)!}"
        target="_blank" onclick=${(application.setEmploymentAgreementPrinted(true))!"-"}>
       <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-new-window"></span>
        pdf</a></#if></td>
```

This is the builder set method

```
public Builder setEmploymentAgreementPrinted(Boolean employmentAgreementPrinted) {
  isEmploymentAgreementPrinted = employmentAgreementPrinted;
 return this;}
```

Comment: is this ftl or php? If you are not redirecting to external domain, can u handle this logic inside the new controller method that you are triggering in new tab?

Comment: it is ftp. Once you click on the pdf it does open it into  a new tab

Comment: I believe controller for this url "/store/${(storeId)!}/view/new/${(application.id)!}" is in your application only, so add code to set boolean variable inside this controller.

Comment: isn't that what the public builder setemploymentAgreementPrint(Boolean ) is?

Comment: But I dont think this will get triggered since page is getting redirected here. Another simple fix is to trigger a java script method on click which contains "setemploymentAgreementPrint(Boolean )" and then redirect to new tab from that function. But I recommend you to set the variable from java, because how to handle a condition where u set the varaibale here but pdf download failed in new tab?

Comment: I changed it a bit now it just opens up the pdf and uses a o'clock method that calls a js function like you suggest but how do I call the setEmp method there in the javascript function?

Comment: if your onclick=${(application.setEmploymentAgreementPrinted(true))!"-"} is a valid one, please use the same in new jquey function